# Reformatting a single messy column

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012, format

I have a really funny data set that was provided to me by a colleague. The data set is in SQL Server 2014. I have a table in there called 'Users', with a column names Address. The format of the address is a mess:

`|Address                                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|-----------------------
|9, Layman drive, Paris, 32432                    |
|Layman drive, Paris, 9832, #AALM,43              |
|Layman drive, Paris, 33, #AM,1                   |
|11, Layman drive, Paris                          |
|12, Layman drive, Paris                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|-----------------------`

I am trying to re-arrange all the address items in the following format:

**[Address Number], [Street], [City], [Postcode]**

**9, Layman Drive, Paris, 32432**

At the same time I need to get rid of characters like this:  '#AALM,43'

Anyone know where I can begin?

Thanks.

Comment: I would clean it with a different tool like C# instead of SQL. But even then it's not clear if it's possible at all. It's really a mess. There don't seem to be any rules.

Comment: I always like to fix the future before I fix the past.  In this case, do something to ensure new records have the format you want.  In fact, I'd go for separate fields.  Also, your desired format does not take apartment numbers into account.

Comment: This looks like a job for regex.

Comment: I too would recommend a regex (don't know how easy that is in SQL Server - you might have to use a different tool like C# (suggested above) or Java). It looks like the format is something like the following: `[Address Number,] Street, City [,Postal Code] [,extra junk]` (where the fields in square brackets may or may not exist? Am I right?

Comment: If so, here is a regex that may be of assistance: `^((\d+),\s*)?(([^,]+),\s*)(([^,]+),\s*)(\d+)?` The address number will be in group 2 (`\2` or `$2`), the street in group 4, the city in group 6, the postal code in group 7. Hope this helps.

Comment: your question says sql server 2014, but tag is sql server 2012? which one right?

Comment: You possibly can use an external service, like [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) to get geodata (and structured address data) rather than messing around with regex. It is relatively easy to implement a client for these webservices in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Having done cleaning like this in the past, it is something you definitely want to do in pieces, especially directly from SQL, such as through the SQL query interface.

I would start by modifying your table structure and adding the additional columns you want -- IN ADDITION to an EXTRA column for "workingAddress" (or abbreviated to "wadr" for brief in your queries).

Then, copy all your address column values to the temp work address column so we don't destroy your original one...

```
update yourTable set wadr = Address;
```

Then, work one column component at a time and do something LIKE...

```
update yourTable
   set [Address Number] = LTRIM( RTRIM( LEFT( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) -1 )))
   where CHARINDEX(',', wadr) > 1;
```

Then, KEEP only those that ARE just numeric representations of an address number

```
update yourTable
   set [Address Number] = ''
   where LTRIM( RTRIM( STR( cast( [Address Number] as Integer ), 6 ))) = RTRIM([Address Number]);
```

Now, for those that were SUCCESSFULLY KEPT, strip off from the work address column

```
update yourTable
   set wadr = LTRIM( RTRIM( SUBSTR( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) +1, 60)))
   where LEN( RTRIM( [Address Number] )) > 0;
```

So now, your address number (when present) will be in your [Address Number] column and that number has been stripped from the "wadr" column and trimmed down to just the street...  Now, process for the street:

```
update yourTable
   set [Street] = LTRIM( RTRIM( LEFT( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) -1 )))
   where CHARINDEX(',', wadr) > 1;
```

And strip off the street from the work address column

```
update yourTable
   set wadr = LTRIM( RTRIM( SUBSTR( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) +1, 60)))
   where LEN( RTRIM( [Street] )) > 0;
```

Now on to the City and then strip where City is found...

```
update yourTable
   set [City] = LTRIM( RTRIM( LEFT( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) -1 )))
   where CHARINDEX(',', wadr) > 1;
```

And strip off the street from the work address column

```
update yourTable
   set wadr = LTRIM( RTRIM( SUBSTR( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) +1, 60)))
   where LEN( RTRIM( [City] )) > 0;
```

And finally your postal code...  This could be 2 conditions... If no comma remaining just grab whatever may be left... some of your sample data has NO postal code.  This will first grab the post code from the wadr, then clear the wadr column if no more commas.

```
update yourTable
   set [Postcode] = wadr,
       wadr = ''
   where CHARINDEX(',', wadr) < 1;
```

Now, for those that had a postal code AND something else (your garbage at the end), just grab whatever is prior to the comma like the earlier instances

```
update yourTable
   set [Postcode] = LTRIM( RTRIM( LEFT( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) -1 )))
   where CHARINDEX(',', wadr) > 1;

update yourTable
   set wadr = LTRIM( RTRIM( SUBSTR( wadr, CHARINDEX(',', wadr) +1, 60)))
   where LEN( RTRIM( [Postcode] )) > 0;
```

At the end, your "wadr" column should either be blank, or just have the content of the garbage stuff at the end.  The syntax may need to be adjusted some, but SHOULD do the trick...  Once these are all good to go, confirm things look good and you can delete the "wadr" column and if you want, eventually kill off the "Address" column.

Comment: for so much efforts(either OP going to use it or not but take something from it) + 1

Comment: @Piyush, yup, but doing cleaning in the past and not destroying original values, you would still need to do some sort of parsing / splitting... and if not doing regEx or writing a complete C# app to  convert and update, this would be a one-time cleanup and throw away.